# Kafka Stream - Recycle state every morning

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KafkaStream` application with multiple joins on `KTable`. Finally I am using `Processor Api` to form **State Store** to perform some sort of business logic. Earlier I had a purge job which was deleting `Kafka` log and `KafkaStream's` `state dir` every morning to process only today's data which was produced by my `producers`. Till this time everything was working as expected.

But deleting Kafka log directory is not good approach so I decided to make use of `cleanup.policy` to delete data from Kafka and deleting KafkaStream `state dirs`. I think this approach is creating problem in `state stores` where data is still being re-stored from `changelog` topics on App startup.

Is there a way to purge entire data from `Kafka` and all `KafkaStream's state store` along with `changelog` topics?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: just to make this clear - you wish to completely purge your state store (& changelog) every 24 hours (for example, every morning at 10AM) ?

Comment: @DorWeid Yes, that's correct.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how I would address this issue. You can look at this great [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/#details) blogpost. I believe a combination of a periodic state store purger(using `Transformer` API) + `KafkaStreams.cleanUp()` could potentially solve your issue